# Answered a closed question?

Tags: bug, support, status-bydesign, answers, closing

A picture is worth a thousand words:
[alt text http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/answered_closed.png](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/answered_closed.png)

Perhaps the user had the browser opened for 8 hours?

[Question in question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1171/are-the-no-cd-cracks-legally-legitimate-closed)

Comment: +1 for a really awesome bug report, and moreso for freehand circles ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the user *did* have their answer started eight hours ago before they came back to finish their little riposte.

[If it's still the same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38228/incorrectly-able-to-answer-a-closed-question), there is no upper limit on when a question can still be answered so long as the answer was started before the question was actually closed.

Comment: at least he is doing his research ;)